# Is it possible to view m2m relation in the admin view of the model that didn't define it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, admin

I have two models and one of them defines m2m relation.

For example:

```
class A(models.Model)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=64)

class B(models.Model)
    style = models.ManyToManyField(A, blank=True)
```

When I view instance of `B` in the admin interface I can see `style` field with instances of `A` that I can multi-select.

Is there a way for me to see which instances of `B` are related to an instance of `A` when I view it in the admin interface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible with `InlineModelAdmin`.

See an example in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models